# How can I add paypal express checkout button to all products in category page in magento?

Tags: magento, paypal

I searched a lot but could not found. I want like each products in category page should have paypal express checkout button

Will that be possible? If yes then please tell how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you should be able to do that by overwriting Add to card controller or write your own controller. This is what I would do:

1. Build your button Html, adding an extra POST variable, says express_checkout=1
2. In your controller, check $_POST['express_checkout']
3. If true, set Payment method = PayPal Express, redirect to Paypal.

Comment: Glad I can help, this may be difficult to implement, but possible